# How to declare a compile-time constant list of different size lists in a constant header file?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

## Introduction

Good day,

I want to optimize my application and especially a constant header file. In order to do so, I define inline constexpr constants in order to avoid multiple copies of those variable in files they are included. And also to have compile-time constants.

I want now to add a new inline constexpr variable/arrays and this complexifies the constant header files. I want a list/array of a certain fixed size containing lists/arrays, each of them of different sizes. Finally, I would like an easy way of using it and easy accessibility.

---

## Planned work

In the following, I note CONST to denot that the CONST values are compile-time constants.
I wanted to implement my constant lists/arrays, that are later needed to be contained in a parent list/array (all defined in the constant header file), as:

```
inline constexpr std::array<CONST int, size1> first = { some CONST values };
inline constexpr std::array<CONST int, size2> second= { some other CONST values };
inline constexpr std::array<CONST int, size3> third = { some other CONST values };
```

Now, the idea is to access each array via a parent list for simplicity, if possible:

```
CONTAINER parent = { first, second, third };
```

---

## Problems

Now I see problem arrising when I want to manipulate the arrays. Ideally, I would like the children (first, second and third) to behave as std::vector<int> and the parent as std::vector<std::vector<CONST int>*>. Because I could access first via a std::vector<CONST int>* pointer and I could change the pointed vector like the following:

```
// Initialization
std::vector<CONST int>* current_vec = nullptr;
...
// First assignation
current_vec = parent[0];
...
// Reassignation
current_vec = parent[1];
...
```

But this implementation uses vector. With std::array, I think my pointer could not do the thing because it needs to know the size of each child arrays. Also, maybe I could do something with iterators but same problem (auto keyword might be a solution?).

So, what I did for now is to use std::vector and define the child arrays as:

```
inline const std::vector<int> first = { some CONST values };
inline const std::vector<int> second = { some other CONST values };
inline const std::vector<int> third = { some other CONST values };
```

And afterwards, I define the parent as:

```
inline constexpr std::array<const std::vector<CONST int>*, 3> parent = {&first, &second, &third};
```

I can access the children like expected above:

```
const std::vector<CONST int>* to_access = parent[0];
```

It seems to work and I think the vectors are compiled-const (I guess so, if not, I wouldn't be able to compile the inline constexpr parent?).

---

## Question

First, do you find the approach meaningful and is there something I don't see know that actually make my solution wrong? Secondly, would you use another container or another solution with constexpr rather than a const vector, an alternative that I am maybe not aware of (maybe constexpr functions or working with iterators)?

I hope everything is clear. I thank you in advance for your advises and help.

**Note**

I know that we can define constexpr vector since c++20 but I think it works only with the msvc c++20 compiler so I want to avoid that solution.

Comment: So why not `std::array<std::array<int, size>, 3>`? `But this implementation uses vector` Don't you get a wall of errors on `current_vec = parent[0];` like "assignment from int to a pointer to `std::<vector>` is invalid"? `I define the parent as:` Don't you get wall of warnings like "converting a pointer to std::array to std::vector"?

Comment: @KamilCuk Hello and thanks for your response but I think you should reread the question. First, I don't want to create a parent with fixed size children for many reasons (for example, if first is of size 1 and second of size 20, that is a waste of memory). Now considering current_vec assignation: parent[0] is a std::vector<int>\* as current_vec. Finally, the parent I define is ok since the children are std::vectpr<int>. So no warnings are happening as expected.

Comment: I do not understand. You laid out "planned work", then specified problems on something different. Could you ask _specific short_ question? Please kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - a wall of text is a wall. My Q: do you want the arrays to be immutable or not? Constexpr or not? Are you searching for a container to lay them together, or for a type to assign them to? How do you intent to access them? And why not just write a class encapsulating it all? Do you want to access them in constexpr context?

Comment: `I think the vectors are compiled-const` The _pointers_ to vectors are constexpr `&first`. All data _inside_ vector are allocated dynamicaly, are not constexpr at all.

Comment: You could use a `std::span` as a parent. You don't need the parent to hold the children. And if you do, you'll have to make a custom class, not use a std container. Containers are for one type of child class.

Comment: @KamilCuk My question is indead unclear. In simple words, I would like to have a compile-time list of list of different sizes. The best way to force this is, I guess, using constexpr. As I am putting constants in the child lists, I want everything to be immutable. I was thinking that some kind of container is the best choice to later use them by indexing the parent container. But now that you mention the constexpr class it could also be a nice way (but indexing is perfect for my application). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you want to do that? Why multi-level unnamed contants? What's the problems with constants inside namespace/class? Why an array of compile-time constants? **You might be using the wrong tool from the job** and without a context, it is hard to know. Unless you really need multi-level compile-time arrays which I doubt, this is not a good solution. Naming constants by an index is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may give you ideas:

```
#include <array>
const int size1 = 1;
const int size2 = 2;
const int size3 = 3;

constexpr std::array<int, size1> first = { 1 };
constexpr std::array<int, size2> second= { 2 };
constexpr std::array<int, size3> third = { 3 };

#include <variant>
// The safest, I guess, annoying to use.
constexpr std::array<
    std::variant<decltype(first), decltype(second), decltype(third)>,
    3> parent1 = {
        first, second, third
};

// The simplest - no bounds information.
constexpr std::array<const int *, 3> parent2 = {
    first.data(), second.data(), third.data()
};

// Tie bounds together with pointers.
constexpr std::array<std::pair<const int *, std::size_t>, 3> parent3 = {{
    { first.data(), first.size(), },
    { second.data(), second.size(), },
    { third.data(), third.size(), },
}};

// In C++20 we now have span
#include <span>
constexpr std::array<std::span<const int>, 3> parent4 = {{
    first, second, third
}};

// Compile-time template access.
template<int index>
constexpr auto parent5() {
    if constexpr (index == 0) {
        return first;
    } else if constexpr (index == 1) {
        return second;
    } else if constexpr (index == 2) {
        return third;
    }
}
```

I think accessing uniformly 3 arrays with *different* sizes is asking for out-of-bounds trouble. Remember to check bounds to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: Although this works, it's a needlessly complex solution. It would be the fix of an xy problem. Making a new design for the underlying problem would be a better approach